# How can I send a single message to multiple services at once (Email, Skype, Twitter, etc)?

Tags: email, skype, twitter, messaging

I'd like to be able to notify my friends when I'm about to stream live.  The problem is that there isn't really one messaging service that they all use.  Some use Twitter, some only go on Skype or Steam... you get the idea.

So, I'm wondering if there's a way I can type a quick message and send it out to a number of various services without having to repeat the message to each service individually.

Is there something out there that already does this? ...or perhaps I can set something up myself (I'm a web developer and I realize I would need the API per service)?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There's a site called "if this then that", [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/). You can set it up to take certain actions when triggered by another action. You can link channels such as Twitter, Gmail, Facebook, and more. I don't think there is Skype or Steam available though.

Wikipedia has a list of the available channels: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IFTTT#List_of_channels

Comment: I have used that site before.  I was trying to use it to automatically share my new YouTube uploads, and it wouldn't work, so I sorta just gave up on the site.  I hadn't thought about using it for what I'm trying to do now.  I'll give it a try.  Thanks!